# Does only adding a new Entity require Core Date Migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, swift, migration

I have an app that already uses Core Data and I now would like to add a new Entity with its own attributes to Core Data.  When doing this, I will not be touching any other Entities.

I would assume that this would require Core Data Migration; however, upon adding this Entity, my app still appears to work correctly with no Core Data issues.

I am happy to proceed with migrating my data, I just do not want to waste my time doing so if it is not required.

Comment: Did you have a look at the checklist in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html ?

Comment: Yes migration needed.Even if you change the attribute of any of the existing entities you need core data migration. refer this tutorial which i found very useful http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-migrations--cms-21844

Comment: Thanks everybody.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need manual migration.

1. Add a new version for the data model.
2. Add the new entity to the new
   model.
3. Select the new data model as the current model.